# Load region with C3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to dynamically load a region to a line chart in C3.js using the load api.

The column data loads fine but there is no change to the regions. I don't want to use the regions.add api because I require a dashed line for this project.

```
chart.load({
    columns:[
        ['data2', 10, 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50]
    ],
    regions: {
         'data2': [{'start':3, 'style':'dashed'}]
    }
    });
```

I would really appreciate any help, I am so stuck - thank you!

Comment: First, your `regions` doesn't look like [what their api demonstrates](http://c3js.org/reference.html#regions). Second, `regions` sits outside of `data` not inside like `columns`. To change these dynamically you might have to do something different.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not using the regions api as that cannot give a dashed line effect. I am using the line chart with regions approach where regions is put inside the data object as in this example http://c3js.org/samples/simple_regions.html

Comment: Touche. You can't emulate the effect with CSS? Otherwise, you might want to consider opening an issue on the official [github page](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3).

Comment: No. The line is svg. I have opened it on Github but so far nobody knows.

Comment: chart.regions.add({axis: 'x', start: '3', end: '3', class: 'region_new'})

Comment: @bernie2436 in c3 the dashed region is made using the d attribute of the path. Its not made using CSS style as you are assuming, adding a class will apply the style to full path and not to the dashed region. :)

Answer (score 4):

As per their documentation [c3 api load](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load) you can only pass these values in `load` call

`url`, `json`, `rows`, `columns`, `classes`, `categories`, `axes`, `colors`, `type`, `types`, `unload` and `done`

To add `regions` to `load` call you need to raise issue with them on their [github pages](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues) or check if one already exists

As of now only solution is to use [regions.add](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-regions-add) but it does not support dash style as of now

check [Demo:Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85oprvvp/4/)

You can raise an issue to add dash style instead of adding `regions` to `load` call as it may be easier and faster for them to fix

Comment: Updated the demo link, copied the whole javascript as fiddle was blocking raw github content url